# Программирование сокетов

Tags: php, сокет

Есть вопросы по работе с сокетами посредством PHP:

- что делает `socket_accept()` если на сокет в данный момент никто на подключается  ?
- Имеет ли смысл делать `sleep()` перед `socket_read()` или `socket_write()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну [тут](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-accept.php) вот все написано нормально

> After the socket socket has been
> created using socket_create(), bound
> to a name with socket_bind(), and told
> to listen for connections with
> socket_listen(), this function will
> accept incoming connections on that
> socket. Once a successful connection
> is made, a new socket resource is
> returned, which may be used for
> communication. If there are multiple
> connections queued on the socket, the
> first will be used. If there are no
> pending connections, socket_accept()
> will block until a connection becomes
> present. If socket has been made
> non-blocking using
> socket_set_blocking() or
> socket_set_nonblock(), FALSE will be
> returned.
>
> The socket resource returned by
> socket_accept() may not be used to
> accept new connections. The original
> listening socket socket, however,
> remains open and may be reused.

А, да, там если что можно русский язык выбрать и прочитать на родном для себя :)